# What does 'category' mean in the NEW NAVAID menu of the Airbus FMS?

Tags: landing, airport, airbus, automation

I tried to create a NEW NAVAID in the Flight Management System because I was simulating a flight to an airport that is not in the database of the FMS.

What Category is Airbus referring to in the MCDU menu:

- DATA > Next Page > NAVAID > 2R, (*see image below*).

I don't understand why a LOC DME has categor y= 0? What it's RNP or ILS DME? which category should I insert?

[image: screenshot of the FMS MCDU display]

Reference: FCOM> Aircraft System> Auto Flight-Flight Management> Control and Indicators> MCDU-Page Description> NAVAID/PILOT'S NAVAID> NEW NAVAID Pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [precision instrument approach category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system#ILS_categories), CAT I (1), CAT II (2) or CAT III (3). LOC DME doesn't have an approach category because it provides only lateral guidance with no vertical support, so a precision instrument approach is not possible.

Comment: Noted, thank you :)